# Trying to build this CSS grid

Tags: css, grid, offset, css-grid

I successfully created the grid, with the CSS display:grid; property, like this:

1 2
3 4
5 6

But I'm struggling with creating the offset, like this:

http://share.activ.is/Yjy8xZ

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(2n) {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: red border is added for quick visibility.

Comment: that simple!!!! Thank you very much!